# Angular $watch event works while the nearly identical function on ng-init doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two functions calls in *Angular* the first one is called in the `ng-init` event using this:

```
ng-init="dateCall()"
```

And the function is:

```
$scope.dateCall = function() {
    var date, endDate;
    $scope.start_date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    date = new Date($scope.start_date);
    $scope.season = $scope.fundraiser_seasons.find(function(e) {
        return Date.create(e.start_date) <= date && date <= Date.create(e.end_date);
    });
    endDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.season.end_date), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    return $scope.end_date = endDate;
};
```

Which for some reason will not return a value for `$scope.season`. However this almost identical event works completely fine whenever I change the value for `$scope.start_date.`

```
$scope.$watch("start_date", function(start_date) {
    var date, endDate;
    if ($scope.fundraiser_seasons.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    date = new Date(start_date);
    $scope.season = $scope.fundraiser_seasons.find(function(e) {
        return Date.create(e.start_date) <= date && date <= Date.create(e.end_date);
    });
    endDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.season.end_date), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    return $scope.end_date = endDate;
});
```

I've been troubleshooting this forever and can not get it to work and feel like I must be missing something stupid. Basically I just want it to return that `end_date` based on todays day when the app loads - and I know the return of that value works fine in the `$watch` function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can call the `dateCall()` in the controller?

Comment: `$scope.dateCall` returns some value, but where in the code you are getting that returned value. ?`ng-init` will invoke this method but the returned value will be use less

Comment: $watch() is generally used inside a directive instead of a controller. Also like the comment has mentioned init() is called once when the controller initialized, since $watch calls its listener once when initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have an empty array in `$scope.fundraiser_seasons` when it's used in the NgInit event.

Instead of storing the same logic in two seperate function refactor the code to use the same logic like this

```
$scope.dateCall = function() {
    $scope.start_date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    var date = new Date($scope.start_date);
    calcDate(date);
};

$scope.$watch("start_date", function(start_date) {

    var date = new Date(start_date);
    calcDate(date);
});

var calcDate = function(date){

    if ($scope.fundraiser_seasons.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.season = $scope.fundraiser_seasons.find(function(e) {
        return Date.create(e.start_date) <= date && date <= Date.create(e.end_date);
    });
    var endDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.season.end_date), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    return $scope.end_date = endDate;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus! It does seem to be an empty array in that init call which was throwing it off. Thanks for the idea on refactoring though, that helps in consistency a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the return value from the ng-init, you can assign it

```
ng-init="result=dateCall()"
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the return value from the $watch.
return to who? its meaningless.